# How to read and transpose big data set into R

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata

I am trying to read and transpose a data set within more than 18,000 rows and 90 columns into R. (Because the data set is actually including 18,000 variables, and 90 samples.) I tried `read.transpose` but does not work. Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order to make this question more useful to others, please edit your question to say where `read.transpose` came from (the `Ecfun` package?), include a sample of the code you tried, and why it did not work (what was the error message?).  It would also be very useful to include some sample data that reproduces the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/134830.

Answer (score 3):

Actually that is a pretty average/small data set. Just read it in like you would any data frame. Then the function you are looking for is `t()`, use `?t` for more information

Comment: `test <- data.frame(matrix(1:10,nrow=18000,ncol=90)); system.time(t(test));` == 0.02 seconds for me. Should be quick enough.